# How to loop user input until a sum is reached?

Tags: java, loops, payment

I am very new to Java and StackOverflow (so I hope this question and answer aren't already posted on here). I am writing a code for a vending machine and I need to create a loop so that it continues to ask the user for input until the cost of the item is reached. How would I go about this?

```
        System.out.println("Please enter payment of: $" + totalCost); // asking client to pay amount
    double pay1; // this is the name given to the first value of money the client enters
    pay1 = keyboard.nextInt();
        if (pay1 > totalCost) {
      System.out.println("You entered: $" + pay1);
      System.out.println("Change needed: $" + (pay1 - totalCost));
    }   else {
      System.out.println("You entered: $" + pay1);
      System.out.println("Please enter payment of: $" + (totalCost - pay1));
            }
    double pay2; // next value of money input by customer
    pay2 = keyboard.nextInt();
    double totalPaid = (pay1 + pay2);
    if (totalPaid > totalCost) {
      System.out.println("You entered: $" + pay2);
      System.out.println("Change needed: $" + (totalPaid - totalCost));
  } else {
      System.out.println("You entered: $" + pay2);
      System.out.println("Please enter payment of: $" + (totalCost -          totalPaid));
    }
    }
    }
```

Comment: can you please show what you have tried so far?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the op fails to show any effort and just looks for a piece of cake to scarf down

Comment: Sorry, please see the latest edit - I hope it is what you were looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Can you be more specific? The pseudo code would probably look like this:

```
while(money < desiredMoney) {
    askForMoney();
}
```

Comment: In the while statement? Or somewhere else?

Comment: in boolean expression that goes in while? I may be wrong but to me equal is right relational operator?

Comment: In the scenario described, you want to continue asking for money as long as you have less money than you need. As soon as you have enough or more than enough, you exit the loop.

Comment: k good caugth if it is gonna be equal so never go through the while loop good point